# iOS - how to wrap asynchronous call inside synchronous method call

Tags: ios, asynchronous, static-libraries, synchronous

I have a wrapper static ios sdk. It wraps other sdks and performs asych tasks. But wrapper sdk must expose a method which should be a synchronous call. Consumer of wrapper sdk calls the synchronous method. But inside it should call asynch methods where result will be fetched in delegate methods that are implemented. But how to pass result to consumer? How to make synchronous call to wait till asynch tasks get completed?

Here is the flow : UI Controller --synch call--> wrapper lib --asynch call-->dependent lib task execution.

This dependent lib have delegated protocols. Results of asynch tasks will be received in -(void)results:(custom class)obj{}. this is implemented in a class of wrapper lib. Now how to send this to UI controller?

I cant use notifications and also no provision to send a block to 'dependent lib task' as a completion handler.

Comment: This is normally done using a completion block.  This also has nothing to do with static libraries.

Comment: Yeah. But I cant use blocks since already other sdk is using delegates implementation for asynch tasks. I cant  send use completion handler on those asynch tasks. Sdks are not providing those.

Comment: Sorry this question really lacks detail.